# Finding a String Palindrome with a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

I am trying to write a recursive function that will determine if a string is a palindrome. Here is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    string word = "madam";

    if (palindrome(word) == true)
        cout << "word is a palindrome!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "word is not a palindrome..." << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool palindrome(string word)
{
    int length = word.length();

    string first = word.substr(0,1);
    string last = word.substr((length - 1), 1);

    if (first == last)
    {
        word = word.substr((0 + 1), (length - 2));
        cout << word << " " << word.length() << endl;  // DEBUGGING
        if (word.length() <= 1) return true;  // Problem line?
        palindrome(word);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

For some reason when the recursive function gets deep enough, and word.length() is less than or equal to 1, It doesn't return true. I can't seem to figure out why. Is it something to do with how recursive functions work, or how I am readjusting the length of word in the line before I commented DEBUGGING?

I am not as talented at C++ as I should be, so please excuse me if my programming seems poor.

Comment: `word.substr((0 + 1)` Isn't that always 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are at least missing a return statement here:

```
    if (word.length() <= 1) return true;  // Problem line?
    return palindrome(word);    // ###### HERE !
}
else
    return false;
```

If the length is not 1 you are calling recursively the `palindrome` function, ignoring its return value and then returning always `false`. With my fix, you will return the result of the palindrome function called with word after removing the first and last letter.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by hivert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22890959/3422652) identified your problem but in case you are at all concerned with performance consider using iterators or indices rather than making many string copies. Perhaps something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool palindrome(T begin, T end){
  if (end - begin <= 1 )
    return true;

  --end;
  if (*begin != *end)
    return false;

  ++begin;
  return palindrome(begin, end);
}

int main() {
  std::string word(10000,'a');

  if (palindrome(word.cbegin(), word.cend()) == true)
    std::cout << "word is a palindrome" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "word is not a palindrome" << std::endl;
}
```

But if you want to check a very long string you could get a stack overflow. If you are lucky the compiler might perform [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Of course in this case it is easy to remove the recursion and use a loop instead:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool palindrome(T begin, T end){
  while(end - begin > 1) {
    --end;  
   if (*begin != *end)
      return false;
    ++begin;
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  std::string word(1000000000,'a');

  if (palindrome(word.cbegin(), word.cend()) == true)
    std::cout << "word is a palindrome" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "word is not a palindrome" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 string palindrome(string a, string b)
  {
    if (a.length() == 1 && a == b)
    return "true";
    else if (a.substr(0, 1) == b.substr(b.length() - 1, b.length() - 1)) return palindrome(a.substr(1), b.substr(0, b.length() - 1));
    else return "false";
  }
```

Comment: Explain your answer so that it's easy to understand for the future users.

Comment: Interesting, but very expensive. You're probably better off passing a pair of indexes and returning when equal or pass.

Comment: Expensive is an understatement, this code can create an excessive number of temporary strings. It will also throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if the second parameter is an empty string. Finally, a sane implementation would return `bool`.