# Find Palindrome

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion, palindrome

I want to find Palindrome of a word. Whats Wrong Here?

main function:

```
  int size;
  string input;
  cin>>input;
  size = input.length();  
  if(testPalindrome(input,size-1,0))
    cout<<"It's Palindrome";
  else
    cout<<"It's not Palindrome";
```

And the testPalindrome function is:

```
bool testPalindrome (string pal , int last, int first){

    if (pal[first] != pal[last])
        return false;
    else{
        if (first<last)
            testPalindrome(pal,last-1,first+1);
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890946/finding-a-string-palindrome-with-a-recursive-function) and found the answer for determining Palindromes, but why this one is not working?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: There are paths in your `testPalindrome` that doesn't return anything. That leads to *undefined behavior*. A good compiler should have shouted warnings at you for it.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working". There are countless ways that a program can "not work".

Comment: Why don't you compile with warnings turned on? `main.cpp:16:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function` should help you.

Comment: You must have forgot to read the accepted answer to that other question, since you reproduced exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the return statement in the function

```
    if (first<last)
        return testPalindrome(pal,last-1,first+1);
        ^^^^^^^
```

Usually the first parameter of a range specifies the lower value and the second parameter specifies either the upper value of the range that is not included in the range or the number of elements in the sequence..

And the first parameter should be declared as having constant reference type because the string itself is not changed and you will escape additional memory allocation.

The recursive function can be written like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool testPalindrome(const std::string &s,
    std::string::size_type i,
    std::string::size_type n)
{
    return n < 2 || (s[i] == s[n-1] && testPalindrome(s, i + 1, n - 2) );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << testPalindrome("abba", 0, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << testPalindrome("aba", 0, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << testPalindrome("aa", 0, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << testPalindrome("a", 0, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << testPalindrome("ab", 0, 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
1
1
1
0
```

The simplest way to check whether an object of the type `std::string` is a palindrome is to write the expression

```
s == std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() )
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to return the result of the recursive call, just like when you call any other function.

If you don't, the behaviour is undefined.